# Remove a SQL Server Patch only visible in View Installed Update List

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, clustering, windows-server, patching

Kindly help me regarding our issue with a Clustered Environment's applied patch.

The situation is: We removed a SQL Patch: GDR 6248 for SQL Server 2012 (KB3194721) (64 bit). When we successfully removed the patch on the first node, we rebooted it. Now when we tried to remove it on the second node, we can't proceed to uninstall the patch as there are missing files.

We attempted to remove the patch again using some ready `msi` files on our repository. We successfully removed the patch. SQL Management Studio detects the correct service pack, which is SP3.

The issue now is on the OS where the patch we're trying to remove is still on the View Installed Updates List. Please advise how to remove it? What steps to take that is least harmful to the clustered setup?

OS Version: Windows Server Enterprise 2012
Database Version: SQL Server 2012 SP3

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like an orphaned registry entry. The steps in [this article](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/manually-remove-programs-from-add-remove-programs/) outline how to back up the uninstall key and delete unwanted entries:

1. Click Start, then click on Run and type regedit in the Open field. Then press enter on your keyboard.
2. Navigate to the Registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall. You do this by clicking on the plus sign next to each key in the path to expand the path below it. For example you will click on the plus next to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Software, Microsoft, Windows, CurrentVersion, and finally Uninstall.
3. Right click on the the Uninstall key and select the Export option. (If you are using Win98/95/ME, you should clik on the Registry menu and then select Export). This will open up a dialog box where you can select a directory and name for the file you will export to. Make the Save in: field set to your Desktop and in the File name: field enter uninstall_programs and press the Save button. This will create a backup of your Uninstall registry key on your desktop in case of a problem.
4. Now that we have a backup created, we will proceed with deleting the entries for the programs that we would no longer like to appear in your Add/Remove Programs list. As long as the Uninstall key is expanded you will see below it a listing of programs. Search for the program you would no longer like to appear in the Add/Remove Programs list and right click on the name of the program and then click on the Delete key. When it asks for confirmation, click on the Yes key.
5. Once the key is deleted, exit regedit, go back into your Add/Remove Programs option in the Control Panel and see if the program is now gone from the listing. If it is not listed, then you have deleted the entry from the Registry correctly. If on the other hand, the listing looks incorrect you can restore the backup you created by double-clicking on the uninstall_programs.reg icon found in your desktop. When it prompts you if you would like to merge the contents, you would reply Yes. Then you should repeat steps 1 through 5 to remove the desired program.

Comment: Thank you so much SQL_underworld will try the suggested approach and update you of the progress.

Comment: Did this work out for you?